# Saving each iteration of an accumulator?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, counter, accumulator

(Yes this WAS homework, but already completed, I'm just trying to improve it now for practice)

This is basically a sales calculator, that allows you to have multiple inputs for sales items, then displays the total, sales tax, and grand total.

The modification I'm trying to make, is that I want to be able to SAVE the cost of each number of items in a variable, without them overlapping memory, and then be able to call them above the grand total, so you can see what each item was worth.

===========================================================================

```
//importing libraries for cin and cout, as well as setw() and setprecision()
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; //sets all code to standard syntax

int main(){ //initializes the main function

    //initializing variables
    char answer = ' ';
    int saleItems = 0;
    double saleTax = 0.0;
    double grandTotal = 0.0;
    double itemValue = 0.0;
    double titemValue = 0.0;
    double taxPerc = 0.0;

    //begins a post-test loop
    do {
        titemValue = 0.0; //makes sure the accumulator resets WITHIN the loop

        //prompts for sale items amount
        cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
        cin >> saleItems;

        //creates a loop that displays the prompt for each iteration of saleItems
        for (int x = 1; x <= saleItems; x += 1){
            cout << "Enter in the value of sales item " << x << " : $";
            cin >> itemValue;
            titemValue += itemValue; //accumulator for adding up the iterated values
        }

        //prompts the user to enter a sales percentage
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter in the sales tax percentage(Enter 10 for 10%): ";
        cin >> taxPerc;
        cout << endl << endl;

        //processes the variables after taxPerc has been given
        saleTax = titemValue * (taxPerc / 100);
        grandTotal = titemValue + saleTax;

        //sets decimal precision to 2 places
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

        //displays receipt with the calculated and input values
        cout << "********************************************" << endl;
        cout << "********  S A L E S  R E C E I P T  ********" << endl;
        cout << "********************************************" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "**  Total Sales            $" << setw(9) << titemValue << "     **" << endl;
        cout << "**  Sales Tax              $" << setw(9) << saleTax << "     **" << endl;
        cout << "**                          ----------    **" << endl;
        cout << "**  Grand Total            $" << setw(9) << grandTotal << "     **" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
        cout << "********************************************" << endl << endl << endl;

        //prompts user to begin loop again
        cout << "Do you want to run this program again? (Y/N):";
        cin >> answer;
        answer = toupper(answer);
        cout << endl << endl;

        } while (answer == 'Y');
```

===========================================================================

So, essentially, I need to be able to save each itemValue to multiple different values without the loop repeating itself, and just replacing them, and I can't really see how I can do that considering the accumulator will just keep looping, and adding up the itemValue values.

Comment: You want to save each value that was entered so you can print it out again? Use a `std::vector` or `std::list` to store the items in the `for` loop.

Comment: How would I do so using an array? I would like to use a more basic method, because I am a beginner, and it seems like arrays are the next step for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to use an simple array to store the item values.

Declare an array at the top. Note: you will have to give it a fixed size. There are ways to have a variable size, but they get more complex (such as vectors). It is better to specify the size using a constant, rather than a hard coded number, as you will need the constant later.

```
const int maxSaleItems = 100;
double itemValues[maxSaleItems];
```

After you have asked the user for the number of items, max sure they haven't entered a number that is too big.

```
    cout << "How many sales items do you have? : ";
    cin >> saleItems;
    if (saleItems > maxSaleItems) {
        cout << "Sorry, I can only handle " << maxSaleItems << " items.";
        continue;
    }
```

Inside the loop where you are inputting the item values, save the item value to the array:

```
        cout << "Enter in the value of sales item " << x << " : $";
        cin >> itemValue;
        titemValue += itemValue; //accumulator for adding up the iterated values
        itemValues[x - 1] = itemValue;
```

Note the `x-1` in the array access - arrays are 0 based (i.e. their index starts from 0). Normally I would loop `x` from `0` to `< saleItems`, but I didn't want to change your existing loop.

When printing the receipt, add a loop which prints out all the values (you will need to add formatting):

```
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
    for (int x = 1; x <= saleItems; x += 1){
       cout << "** Item " << x << " $" << itemValues[x-1] << "   **" <<endl;
    }
    cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
```

As I said in the comments, using `std::vector` would be better, but if you aren't up to that yet, arrays will do.

Edit: Simple `vector` example.
To add vectors you need to include the appropriate header:

```
#include <vector>
```

No need for `maxSaleItems` any more, as vectors can grow. Declare the vector variable. The `<double>` makes it a vector that contains `double` values:

```
std::vector<double> itemValues;
```

Inside the loop, instead of setting the array value for the new item by location, just add it to the end of the vector using `push_back`.

```
    cout << "Enter in the value of sales item " << x << " : $";
    cin >> itemValue;
    titemValue += itemValue; //accumulator for adding up the iterated values
    itemValues.push_back(itemValue);
```

The printing receipt code, can be left exactly as it was for the array version, as you can access vectors like arrays:

```
cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
for (int x = 1; x <= saleItems; x += 1){
   cout << "** Item " << x << " $" << itemValues[x-1] << "   **" <<endl;
}
cout << "**                                        **" << endl;
```

There are other changes you could do to make the `vector` version simpler, but I wanted to change as little as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something along these lines, I just wish it was easier to create a variable-sized array.

Comment: I'll add in a vector example - they aren't that more complicated.